# Приложение с blur эффектом

Tags: c#, wpf

Как я могу создать подобное приложение, как на скрине?

Я уже смотрел в сторону API от windows, но оно добавляет к размытию ещё и эффект стекла, я не нашел где регулировать силу размытия и как затемнить полупрозрачную область (сделать её ещё более непрозрачной)

Сейчас я смотрю в сторону BlurEffect

```
    <Image x:Name="image">
        <Image.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="25"/>
        </Image.Effect>
    </Image>
```

Но возможно есть варианты лучше, это не кажется мне очень производительным решением.
Или, возможно, я делаю что-то не совсем правильно, буду рад услышать советы по оптимизации

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), «эффект стекла» можно отменить, если не задавать отрицательные маргины в `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`.

Comment: Как регулировать силу размытия, я не нашёл. Вероятно, это не поддерживается, чтобы все приложения были визуально похожи. (Впрочем, я могу тут и ошибаться.)

Comment: А для затемнения просто положите полупрозрачный фон.